# Importing dynamically a dynamic array from another js file

Tags: javascript, arrays, export

I've two js files (main.js, index.js) in a NodeJS environment: in main.js file I've an array that changes in a non-regular way (dinamically) and I need to use that array in index.js;

The array is declared at the beginning of the script; I tried to use the function `export` in main.js but I get the error `Unexpected token 'export'`;

My goal is that the array used in index.js is EXACTLY THE SAME array declared in main.js, so that every change of the array exported are applied *immediately* to the array imported

Here's my attempt:

```
//main.js
TEST = [...] //Changes dinamically
export{TEST}

//index.js
const {TEST} = require('./main.js')
```

Comment: What's the environment? Node, browser, etc.? You can try setting up event listeners for when the array changes so your index file reacts to these changes and updates the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have specified it... it's NodeJS